# How to split a single table into separate tables with x rows each in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a huge table with say a billion rows in postgres with the following schema:

table: collection

| id | uuid | data_1 | data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4343-5454... | data11 | data22 |
| 2 | 3264-4243... | dataxx | datayy |

Here, only id is the primary key (DEFAULT, BIGINT) and rest of the keys do not have any indexes or relations.

I have a third party application which reads data from this table into its RAM and performs operations. But as the size grows, it is limited by its memory.

So I want to split the table into n rows each (decided based on the RAM usage of the application) and save them as separate tables, so that the application can be run in multiple instances and read only a smaller table.

Note: The rows do not change once they've been saved.

I tried to write a simple Python script which just reads from the main table and saves it to a new table, but it takes a lot of time. Is there a way I can do this in Postgresql directly?

Thanks.

Comment: The correct solution is to fix that application. If you can't do that, why not provide multiple views where each only selects a part of that table?

Comment: The third party application is not in my control, only the DB. Is it possible to create views just based on number of rows I want in each view?

Comment: Assuming that you don't have (large) gaps in the IDs, you can use `create view first_part as select * from the_table where id >= 1 and id < 1000000;`  and then `create view second_part as select * from the_table where id >= 1000000 and id < 2000000;`

Comment: Cool, got it. There maybe few gaps in the IDs but that should be fine. Also the number of rows need not be exact, so this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this type of cases is to use **table partitioning**. This is, splitting the original big table into smaller tables (called partitions) based on a certain column (the `id` in your case), so that the queries do not imply searching in the whole table, but just in the appropriate partitions, which is much more efficient.

Check the following PostgreSQL documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html